# XeTeX problem on Debian-based distro

Tags: debian, crunchbang

Was not sure if this should go here or on TeX Stackexchange. Feel free to move if I made mistake. My setup is: GNU/Linux, kernel 2.6.32-5-686, CrunchBang Linux statler. I have installed xetex through apt-get (texlive-xetex).
Problem is that whenever I try to compile a .tex file which LaTeX will compile without problems, I get the following from xetex:

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
>   (Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)

I have installed xelatex, my latex version is

> me@box:~$ latex --version
>   pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
>   kpathsea version 5.0.0

Version of xelatex is

> asha@andromeda:~$ xelatex --version
>   XeTeX 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
>   kpathsea version 5.0.0

Searching, this seems to be related to a recent update to zlib, version zlib-1.2.6. [Source](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3484935&group_id=194926&atid=951385). Other posts reveal that other programs have been affected as well, but I have not been able to find a description of a solution I can use. There was one example where someone reported on seuccessfully linking to the older version of zlib when building the tool in question from sources. This might be a bit above my Linux skills for now.

What can I do with my present distro and setup to have xetex working ?

Comment: [There's a bug report in that](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=659680), apparently it has been fixed in `unstable` (according to [this](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=texlive-xetex), also in `testing`), no idea what Crunchbang uses... so maybe your problem will fix itself soon.

Comment: Thank you. Updating `texlive-binaries` and `texlive-xetex` to the versions mentioned in your links makes it work for me. MAke your comment a reply and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There's a bug report on this issue in Debian's bug tracking system,](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=659680) mentioning that Debian's unstable repositories already have fixed packages (and [the package databases shows that they already hit the Debian/testing repos](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=texlive-xetex)).  Since [Crunchbang 10 "Statler" is based on Debian/*stable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crunchbang#Move_to_Debian), these fixed packages could take some time to be available there;  you can however mix-and-match if you're a little careful (see e.g. [this question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crunchbang#Move_to_Debian)).